# capacitor.js plugin for android onTouchListener

Tags: javascript, java, android, capacitor

I'm currently trying to develop a simple plugin for integrating stylus pen events into an android app.
following the capacitor docs, I've setup my dev environment and was given a template with a simple echo method. I have confirmed that after importing this class to javascript, and running the echo method, I can successfully log on the console that the echo method is working correctly.

I made code changes from this starter template below, take a look:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;

@CapacitorPlugin(name = "MotionEventClass")
public class MotionEventClassPlugin extends Plugin {

    private MotionEventClass implementation = new MotionEventClass();

    @PluginMethod
    public void echo(PluginCall call) {
        String value = call.getString("value");

        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("value", implementation.echo(value));
        call.resolve(ret);
    }

    private class StylusButtonTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("mytag", "Touch event triggered");
        }
    }

    @PluginMethod
    public void setupStylusButtonListener(PluginCall call) {
        // Obtain the activity and root view
        final Activity activity = getBridge().getActivity();
        final View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

        if (activity == null) {
            Log.e("mytag", "Activity is null");
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d("mytag", "Activity obtained successfully");
        }
    
        if (rootView == null) {
            Log.e("mytag", "RootView is null");
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d("mytag", "RootView obtained successfully");
        }
        
        // Create the touch listener and set it on the root view
        final StylusButtonTouchListener stylusButtonTouchListener = new StylusButtonTouchListener();
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(stylusButtonTouchListener);
        Log.d("mytag", "Touch listener set successfully");
        // Notify the JavaScript side that the listener has been set up
        call.resolve();
    }
}
```

---

before listening for stylus input events, I want to do a simple test for the onTouchListener(). So that is why I did not add any stylus-associated code to the plugin yet.

---

then on javascript side:

```
MotionEventClass.echo({ value: 'Hello World!' }).then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
   console.error(error);
});
MotionEventClass.setupStylusButtonListener();
```

when checking my filtered logcat, i can see that touch listener is set successfully.
problem is, touching on the screen doesn't fire any events.

but the events DO fire if i touch on the navigation bar.

possibly because capacitor is rendering the javascript page on the webview.
should i make changes in my plugin class to use webview?
I'm not sure where to go from here. Suggestions would be very much appreciated.